# Issue with nginx, when try to upgrade the package

Tags: nginx, debian, package

I am getting the following error when I try to run

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I am not sure what is the issue. Please guide me. Thanks

```
 Preparing to unpack .../nginx_1.8.0-1~jessie_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking nginx (1.8.0-1~jessie) over (1.6.2-5) ...
    dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx_1.8.0-1~jessie_amd64.deb (--unpack):
     trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/nginx', which is also in package nginx-full 1.6.2-5
    dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx_1.8.0-1~jessie_amd64.deb
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: This question seems more like system administration than programming, so it  should probably have been asked on (http://serverfault.com).  In fact there is a very similar question already there: (http://serverfault.com/questions/469884/upgrading-nginx-full-1-2-1-to-nginx-1-2-6-from-ppa-on-ubuntu-12-10)

Comment: Thanks Joe for pointing it out. Will check there.